# How to set Wix Property from UI which user can change during installation?

Tags: wix, filepath, bootstrapper, wix3

I have Wix Code which simply installs a txt file in the given location

The target location is enclosed in a Property `THISONE`

```
<Fragment>
  <Property Id="THISONE" Value="C:\MyFolder"/>
  <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
    <Directory Id='APPLICATIONFOLDER' ComponentGuidGenerationSeed="{75266e3e-3781-47e3-ac29-46a2d90548f9}">
      <Directory Id='MyFolder' Name='MyFolder'/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <SetDirectory Id='APPLICATIONFOLDER' Value='[THISONE]' />
</Fragment>
  
<Fragment>
  <Component Id="Component1" Directory="MyFolder" Win64="yes">
    <File Id="FirstFile.txt"/>
  </Component>
</Fragment>
```

I want a minimal UI with maybe just a textbox where I can edit the property value so that I can change the target installation file path.

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The WiXUIInstallDir may be what you want, as described in [the WiX documentation](https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html).

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
    <Directory Id='APPLICATIONFOLDER' ComponentGuidGenerationSeed="{75266e3e-3781-47e3-ac29-46a2d90548f9}">
        <Directory Id='MyFolder' Name='MyFolder'/>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

You must set the value of the property `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` to the value of the ID of the directory you want the user to be able to specify the location of, as shown above.  This is then passed to the `WixUI_InstallDir` dialog.  Note that the directory ID must all be uppercase.

If you're using Visual Studio, you'll need to add a reference to `WixUIExtension` to your WiX project.  See [here](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html) for more details.